# How do you dynamically create android launcher shortcuts which link to specific internal pages/parts of a android flutter application

Tags: android, flutter

I would like to copy the following Google Drive functionality in an android flutter application:

Google Drive(on android) allows users to select a file or folder and select "Add to Home screen". This places a link on the androud launcher which does not link to the front page of the google drive app, but rather to the specific file or folder.

[image: View of google drive folder]
[image: View of context menu for google folder:Test]
[image: View after selecting "Add to Home screen"]
[image: Icon generated and placed on Android home]

How do you allow users create launcher icons to specific parts of your application?

Please correct me if I've asked the question inarticulately.

I've discovered the following related questions, which don't quite answer my question:

[Shortcut Add to Android Home Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936778/shortcut-add-to-android-home-screen) Similar but not flutter specific.

[Implement 'Add to Home Screen' in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157202/implement-add-to-home-screen-in-flutter) Unclear and unanswered

[Android add icon to home screen (launcher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052221/android-add-icon-to-home-screen-launcher) Similar but not flutter specific.

[Flutter: Add shortcuts to launcher menu and home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390528/flutter-add-shortcuts-to-launcher-menu-and-home-screen) Closest example but requires internet connection.

[How can I place app icon on launcher home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854197/how-can-i-place-app-icon-on-launcher-home-screen) Outdated and not flutter specific.